# perl one liners + replace complex string with key with any integer value

Tags: regex, perl

we are trying to remove completely the word - `-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=50` from the file `exampl.txt`   ( when value `50` could be any integer value )

for this task we used the following perl one liners , but without success

```
 perl -pi -e 's/\s*\K\Q-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=(^|\s)d{1,2}\E\s*//' exampl.txt
 perl -pi -e 's/\s*\K\Q-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=d{1,2}\E\s*//' exampl.txt 
 perl -pi -e 's/\s*\K\Q-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=[[:digit:]\E\s*//' exampl.txt
```

example of the file:

```
SHARED_HADOOP_DATANODE="-server -XX:ParallelGCThreads=8 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -Xms{{namenode_heapsize}}"
```

any suggestion what is wrong with my perl syntax?

Comment: I see you used my earlier answer without really understanding *how* the regular expression works. Don't do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```bash
perl -i -pe's/-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=\S+\s*//' exampl.txt
```

---

There are a number of problems in your attempts.

- `\Q...\E` escapes all non-word characters except those processed during the string-building phase (`$`, `\E`, `\l`, `\L`, `\u`, `\U` and the delimiter). You absolutely don't want this. `\Q...\E` is almost exclusively used as `\Q$text\E`.
- `d{1,2}` should be `\d{1,2}`. I switched to `\S+` because there's no reason to be more specific.
- `[[:digit:]` should be `[[:digit:]]+`. `\d` is preferred over `[:digit:]`, giving us `[\d]+`, which simplifies to `\d+`.
- `^` doesn't make sense there. It will never match since it matches the start of the string (without the `m` modifier) or the start of a line (with `m`).
- The leading `\s*\K` is useless.